# SQLAlchemy scoped_session is not getting latest data from DB

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm rather new to the whole ORM topic, and I've already searched forums and docs.
The question is about a flask application with SQLAlchemy as ORM for the PostgreSQL.

The __init__.py contains the following line:

`db = SQLAlchemy()`

the created object is referenced in the other files to access the DB.

There is a save function for the model:

`def save(self):
    db.session.add(self)
    db.session.commit()`

and also an update function:

`def update(self):
    for var_name in self.__dict__.keys():
        if var_name is not ('_sa_instance_state' or 'id' or 'foreign_id'):
            # Workaround for JSON update problem
            flag_modified(self, var_name)
    db.session.merge(self)
    db.session.commit()`

The problem occurs when I'm trying to save a new object. The save function writes it to DB, it's visible when querying the DB directly (psql, etc.), but a following ORM query like:

`model_list = db.session.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.foreign_id == this_id).all()`

gives an empty response.

A call of the update function does work as expected, new data is visible when requesting with the ORM.

I'm always using the same session object for example this:
`<sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session object at 0x7f0cff68fda0>`

If the application is restarted everything works fine until a new object was created and tried to get with the ORM.

An unhandsome workaround is using raw SQL like:

`model_list = db.session.execute('SELECT * FROM models_table WHERE
 foreign_id = ' + str(this_id))`

which gives a ResultProxy with latest data like this:

`<sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object at 0x7f0cf74d0390>`

I think my problem is a misunderstanding of the session. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It figured out that the problem has nothing to do with the session, but the filter() method:

`# Neccessary import for string input into filter() function
 from sqlalchemy import text
 # Solution or workaround
 model_list = db.session.query(MyModel).filter(text('foreign_key = ' + str(this_id))).all()`

I could not figure out the problem with:
`filter(MyModel.foreign_id == this_id)` but that's another problem.

I think this way is better than executing raw SQL.